# How can I run a web page in task scheduler every day?

Tags: windows-xp, script, autorun, webpage, task-scheduler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I open a URL on a schedule in the default browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/321215/how-can-i-open-a-url-on-a-schedule-in-the-default-browser)

Tomorrow I will go holiday and I can't connect to internet for 5 days. In my SO account I have 64 consecutive day visit. And I don't wanna lose these days.

I save my SO profile in a web page and saved my desktop.

[image]

But when I run it, opens `file:///C:/Users/Soner/Desktop/Stack%20Overflow.htm` url. So this isn't good for me. Because this isn't count for consecutive day visit.

Is there any way that can I do that with `task scheduler` ? (Like autorun every day.)

Comment: Don't you think that's kinda cheating?

Comment: Do mind that just visiting the page isn't counted as a "visit". Some actions need to be performed, so a program/script that just visits a page won't do anyway. What "actions" need to be performed is one of the great dark secrets of SE! ;) And besides that, SE has very advanced methods of detecting patterns in user activity that may be a result of cheating/fraude. It might pick up visiting activity as well.

Comment: Just visit an internet cafe. Otherwise, what kind of Fanatic are you?

Comment: @SonerGönül Then why do you think you would deserve the Fanatic badge? The badge is there as a reward for an accomplishment. Where's the honour/fun in getting it like that?

Comment: Use a program like One Million Clicks to refresh the page every x hours. But note that in this context this is cheating.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123320/can-badges-be-automated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the Windows [Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) to run your browser's executable `firefox.exe` with the hyperlink of the webpage `http://superuser.com` as the parameter.

You don't want to run a file, you want to run the executable. For you its probably `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" http://superuser.com`. Copy and paste that into the run box. If it opens `superuser.com` in Firefox, that is what you want to put into the task scheduler.

Comment: you dont want to run a file, you want to run the executable.  for you its probably `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" http://superuser.com`  Cut and paste that into the run box.  If it opens superuser.com in firefox, that is what you want to put into the task scheduler.

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Comment: @Keltari, rather than answering in comments I suggest you add that in your answer, though Simon already did you one up

Comment: If you DO want to "run" a file, which really means start the default program for that file type or URI scheme, you want to use the `start` command under Windows, i.e. `start http://webpage.html`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) to do this, as its built right into XP.

> To open Scheduled Tasks, click Start, click All Programs, point to
>   Accessories, point to System Tools, and then click Scheduled Tasks.

Navigate through this, setting up a description for what it will do, a title, etc. When it gets to choosing a program, make sure your action is going straight to the Firefox executable. By default that is c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe (on XP).

Adding a URL in the parameters using "http://url.com" will do it. Specifically for Stack Overflow, use this as your command:

> c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
>   "http://www.stackoverflow.com"

If that did not work, you could also put it into a batch script, and have it kill Firefox after X time, although that is beyond my personal knowledge.

Comment: You could set it to run taskkill /IM firefox.exe 2 minutes later or something.

Comment: I am not on Windows XP - when you setup a task, what are the options?